# Flutter: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, properties

When I tried to build apk, an error occured as following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\projects\app1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> E:\projects\app1\android\key.properties (ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ�����ļ���)

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            6.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

The `build.gradle` from line 27 to line 59 is as following

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app1"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

The `key.properties` is as following:

```
storePassword=password
keyPassword=password
keyAlias=key
storeFile=E:/key.jks
```

It seemed that everything was ok...So how did this error occurred? What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Post full error always. It also says if it's a syntax error or an IOException